# SwiftUIのVStackの書式がよくわからない

Tags: swift, swiftui

SwiftとSwiftUIを学び始めたばかりの初心者です。VStackが構造体ということはわかりました。
`VStack`はあらかじめ定義されたものですが、チュートリアルにあるような`body`の中にかく`VStack`はオーバーライドの記法なのでしょうか？

ここの記法がどういうものなのかを教えていただけると幸いです。

↓AppleのSwiftUIチュートリアルより引用

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Turtle Rock")
                .font(.title)
            Text("Joshua Tree National Park")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SwiftUIについては、functionBuilderなんて、かなり大掛かりな言語機能自体の拡張が関わっているのですが、あなたが引用したような「チュートリアルにあるような`body`の中にかく`VStack`」に関して言うと、**旧来のSwiftにもあったイニシャライザ構文** と言うことになります。

(「構造体では継承やオーバライドはできない」と言う点について、Swift言語としての変更はありません。)

`VStack`には、
[`init(alignment: HorizontalAlignment, spacing: CGFloat?, content: () -> Content)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/vstack/3278367-init)
と言うイニシャライザがありますが、前2つの引数`alignment`と`spacing`は省略可なので、クロージャ型である`content`引数を[trailing closureの構文](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Closures.html#ID102)で呼び出している形になります。

その部分をtrailing closureを使わずに書く(ついでに`return`の省略もやめる)とこんな感じですね:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        return VStack.init(content: {
            Text("Turtle Rock")
                .font(.title)
            Text("Joshua Tree National Park")
        })
    }
}
```

(`body`は単に計算型プロパティ。`.init`なんて普通は書かないですが、ここでは「イニシャライザである」ことを強調するために書いてます。)

---

実はここで起こっているもっと **不思議なこと** は`content`に渡されているクロージャがどうコンパイルされているかにあるのですが、今回は直接のご質問内容には含まれないようなので、触れないでおきます。

ご興味がおありでしたら、[この質問](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/59567/13972)の質問内にあるリンク先(片方は英語ですが)を熟読してみると良いでしょう。